# IFNULL doesn't return the correct field value if its not NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(h.house_ownerID, -1) AS ownerid
FROM house_players AS h
INNER JOIN house_interiors AS hi
    ON h.house_interiorID = hi.house_intLevel
```

This query still returns '-1' to the ALIAS even though the field has value and is not NULL,

[image]

As you can see from the image, it should return (1) if the field is not NULL. or I am just misunderstood the IFNULL function.

Comment: I think the results are correct

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible?  As you suggest, you should not be seeing `-1` for the `ownerid`, at least not that value as a result of the `house_ownerID` being `NULL`.  Better yet, paste a demo for us (http://www.rextester.com) .

Comment: You have to understand the difference between ISNULL and IFNULL. Check the links for simple samples. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_isnull.asp ,    https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood what IFNULL() can do. It is just a function that works row-by-row

Answer (score 0):

IFNULL() works on a row-by-row basis, on each row where you see NULL under home_ownerID so IFNULL() correctly returns minus one in the ownerid column. There is a single row where home_ownerID has a value, and correctly IFNULL() returns that value **for that row only**

[image]

You might be imagining that somehow magically IFNULL() could populate every row with that single value, but it cannot do that.

Comment: Well, what I am trying to do is IF  the home_ownerID is NULL then set the default value to -1 and IF home_ownerID is not NULL then set the value of it from the field where it got fetched.

So, basically.

IF NULL set value to -1
IF NOT NULL set value to what value it is, as long as its not null

Comment: Patrick, we would need to know more about your data and the query to **properly** answer that comment. However the question you asked was *I am just misunderstood the IFNULL function* and yes, you did misunderstand.

Comment: Well this is my house_interiors table https://i.imgur.com/LaQ9qyA.png, this is my house_players table https://i.imgur.com/Fjl8vgl.png. I've accomplished to join them using INNER JOIN. My goal if the house is UNOWNED (NULL) then set the default value -1 on query alias ownerid, and if the house is OWNED (NOT NULL) then set the value to whatever the value is in house_ownerID.

So for example,
house - 1 owned -> NOT NULL
house - 2 - not owned -> NULL

house would return -1 while
house 2 would return the ownerID which in this case 1. Hopefully I've explained it.
@Used_By_Already

Comment: and if the solution was this https://imgur.com/a/ZtJ3D would you transcribe it? Images of data are unfriendly to use and interpret. I urge you to consider opening a new question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a non-NULL value also in the column, then something like this:

```
SELECT h.*, hi.*,
       COALESCE(h.house_ownerID, 
                (SELECT h2.house_ownerId FROM house_players h2 WHERE h2.house_interiorID = h.house_interiorID)
               ) AS ownerid
FROM house_players h INNER JOIN
     house_interiors hi
     ON h.house_interiorID = hi.house_intLevel;
```

Comment: Well I want to load everything even the NULLS as I have usage for them. What I am trying to do is IF house_ownerID is NULL then set the default value to -1 and IF its not NULL then set the value of house_ownerID to whatever the value it has been set.

Comment: if that subquery returns more than one row? how would you decide which one is relevant?

Comment: @Patrick . . . That is what your code is doing.  You appear to want the non-NULL value on all the other rows.

Comment: Yes, what's what my code is doing but it seem to return -1 even on a row that is not NULL, that was my question. For example

My goal if the house is UNOWNED (NULL) then set the default value -1 on query alias ownerid, and if the house is OWNED (NOT NULL) then set the value to whatever the value is in house_ownerID. So for example, house - 1 owned -> NOT NULL house - 2 - not owned -> NULL house would return -1 while house 2 would return the ownerID which in this case 1. @GordonLinoff